other ways to use a theme styling from globalStyles using styled-component on chart.js
I’m working on customizing a line chart in Chart.js for the application I’m building, but I’ve been unable to apply the theme styling from my GlobalStyle setup. I’m using styled-components for my app. I also attempted to dynamically adjust the Chart.js colors, but I encountered an error (see the attached image).
Is there a way to apply my theme props here? The main reason is that my app has a dark/light mode feature, and this is the only approach I know to easily toggle the colors of my elements.
Here’s the code for my chart component:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Chart as ChartJS, LineElement, PointElement, LinearScale, Title, Tooltip, CategoryScale } from 'chart.js';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import styled from 'styled-components';

ChartJS.register(LineElement, PointElement, LinearScale, Title, Tooltip, CategoryScale);

const LineChart = ({ theme }) => {
  // state variables
  const [dataType, setDataType] = useState('Income'); // stores current data type (income, expenses, savings)
  const [isDropdownOpen, setIsDropdownOpen] = useState(false); // manages dropdown state (open/close)
  const [timeRange, setTimeRange] = useState('6 Months'); // stores current time range (by month)

    // chart data & style
    const data = {
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: dataType,
          data: dataType === 'Income' ? [3000, 4000, 3200, 4500, 4800, 5300] :
                dataType === 'Expenses' ? [2500, 3000, 2800, 3500, 3700, 3900] :
                [500, 1000, 400, 1000, 1100, 1400],
          fill: false,
          backgroundColor: theme.containerBackground,
          borderColor: theme.borderColor,
          pointBorderColor: theme.textColor,
          pointBackgroundColor: theme.textColor,
          tension: 0.3,
          pointRadius: 5,
          pointHoverRadius: 7,
        },
      ],
    };
  
    const options = {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: true,
          backgroundColor: theme.textColor,
          titleColor: '#fff',
          borderColor: '#ccc',
          borderWidth: 1,
          bodyColor: "#ddd",
        },
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          grid: {
            display: false,
          },
          // x-axis label
          ticks: {
            color: theme.textColor,
            stepSize: 400
          },
        },
        y : {
          beginAtZero: true,
          grid: {
            color: theme.textColor,
          },
          // y-axis label
          ticks: {
            color: theme.textColor,
            font: {
              size: 14,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };

  return (
    <Container theme={theme}>
   {/* other elements */}
      <ChartContainer>
        <Line data={data} options={options} />
      </ChartContainer>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default LineChart;

enter image description here
I tried to customize this line chart by mapping these colors into Chart.js configuration and dynamically adjust the styling, but I encountered an error (see the attached image).
